# An algorithm that determines if a function f from the finite set A to the finite set B is an onto function.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I write an algorithm that determines if a function f from the finite set A to the finite set B is an onto function.

This is what I have so far:

```
A: array ( members of set A )
B: array ( members of set B )

Mapped: associative array of Boolean variables.

for each b in B:

Mapped[b] = false


for each a in A:

Mapped[f(a)] = true


Onto = true;

for each b in B:

Onto = Onto AND Mapped[b]


return Onto
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me. You get an A.

Comment: Ha ha! Thanks professor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that'll work. A potentially easier approach would be

```
for each a in A:
    remove f(a) from B
return (is B empty?)
```

And then of course you should sort `B` first, so you can remove more quickly.